# Why braise pork in milk?

Tags: milk, pork, braise

Just reading how a high end caterer is fielding requests for pork in milk for Christmas dinner.  I've never heard of that.  What advantage does braising pork in milk give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maiale al latte, or milk-braised pork, is a classic northern Italian preparation, with variations in Tuscany, Veneto, Bologna, among other locales.  Some claim the lactic acid tenderizes the pork. I don't know about that, but when done correctly (IMHO), the milk caramelizes, often curdles, and becomes a delicious, albeit broken, sauce.